Understanding the Fibrant Replacement of a Functor
I am trying to understand the definition of the fibrant replacement of a functor as presented in the book Cubical Homotopy Theory by Munson and Volić [Link]. On page 424, it is defined as follows:
Let $F \colon \mathcal{I} \to \text{Top}$ be a functor. Then its fibrant replacement is a functor $\check{F} \colon \mathcal{I} \to \text{Top}$, defined as follows:
$$
\check{F}(i) := \underset{(i',m) \in \mathcal{I} \downarrow i}{\text{holim}} F(i'),
$$
where $\mathcal{I} \downarrow i$ is the overcategory.
My question is: to compute a homotopy limit over $\mathcal{I} \downarrow i$, we need a functor $\mathcal{I} \downarrow i \to \text{Top}$. What is the functor here whose homotopy limit we are considering?
My thought is that it is the obvious functor $\mathcal{I} \downarrow i \to \text{Top}$, which assigns:

The topological space $F(i')$ for each object $(i', m) \in
   \mathcal{I} \downarrow i$, and

The map $F(f) \colon F(i'_1) \to F(i'_2)$ for each morphism $f \colon (i'_1, m_1) \to (i'_2, m_2)$. (Here, we abuse notation by
writing $f \colon (i'_1, m_1) \to (i'_2, m_2)$ to mean a map $f \colon i_1' \to i_2'$ such that the
composition $i_1' \xrightarrow{f} i_2' \xrightarrow{m_2} i$ is the
same as $i_1' \xrightarrow{m_1} i$.)



You are correct. More concisely, there is an evident projection functor $\pi : \mathcal{I} \downarrow i \to \mathcal{I}$, and we are taking the homotopy limit of the composite $F \circ \pi$. This is similar to the formula for the pointwise right Kan extension of $F$ along the identity on $\mathcal{I}$ (which is naturally isomorphic to $F$), except that we are taking a homotopy limit.
